# apache logs only consider the first vhost of the list

Tags: apache

My server is **Apache 2** on **Debian Stretch** and there are 2 virtual hosts :

- bo.example.com
- example.com

On the log file (/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log), all the visits on example.com are considered as on bo.example.com (which is the first vhost of the list) :

```
bo.example.com:80 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [23/May/2018:14:59:26 +0200] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

Is there a misconfiguration ?

Thanks

Comment: Default hostname.  Personally when I create a vhost I use separate log files, its own documentroot, etc

Comment: Very hard to know since you do not show the configuration...

Comment: which configuration file should I show ?